# Is there an easy way to interpret sortBy and queries coming from Dojo's using Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, dojo, express

A dojo JsonRest will likely send something like this to the server:

```
/FooObject/?foo=value1&sortBy=+foo,-bar
```

I have express and mongodb on the other side.

It's easy enough to get foo. But then, I was just about to write my own function to parse sortBy when I realised: there must be a better way? Surely, this is a common problem which should have an established solution...? Maybe a well-known middleware that is escaping me right now?

I will also need to make it possible to add wildcards (`/FooObject/?foo=value%&sortBy=+foo,-bar` so that anything *starting* with `value` will work. But then again, I wonder if there is some kind of established pattern for this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is  no way to do it... time to write something and place it in GitHub!

Comment: Gotta love it when the answer is "no" :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [qs](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring), which you can install with `npm install qs`:

```
> qs.parse('foo=value%&sortBy=%2bfoo,-bar');
{ foo: 'value%', sortBy: '+foo,-bar' }
```

Comment: Parsing of the query string was never a problem (req.query.foo will do the job fine when using Express). The real issue is more about having a standard library to parse `sortBy` as well as the range options (placed in the headers) provided by Dojo... I mean, it's all stuff that is very easy to write, but...

Comment: Oh sorry... I don't know anything that does that, so you'll probably have to write it yourself.